Fixing Calendar View in SwiftUI
How do I fix these error codes in the images below?
Error Code Pic 1
Error Code Pic 2
I need help fixing a code I was working on for a project. I'm a new dev and this is my first solo project and I'm stomped. I was coding a calendar view, copying a video I saw on YouTube and I copied the exact code but I started getting errors and I would like to know if anyone could help see figure out why.
I was following along with this video here.
This is the code I tried so ar I didn't want to go any further until I resolved these error messages:
Error 1:

Main actor-isolated instance method 'calendarView _:decorationFor:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement.

Error 2:

Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init (wrappedValue:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context.

import SwiftUI

struct CalendarView: UIViewRepresentable {
let interval: DateInterval 
@ObservedObject var eventStore: EventStore

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView {
    let view = UICalendarView()
    view.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    view.availableDateRange = interval
    return view
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(parent: self, eventStore: _eventStore)
    
}


func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICalendarView, context: Context) {
    
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UICalendarViewDelegate {
    var parent: CalendarView
    @ObservedObject var eventStore: EventStore
    init(parent: CalendarView, eventStore: ObservedObject<EventStore>) {
        self.parent = parent
        self._eventStore = eventStore
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
        let foundEvents = eventStore.events
            .filter { $0.date.startOfDay == dateComponents.date?.startOfDay }
        if foundEvents.isEmpty { return nil }
        
        if foundEvents.count > 1 {
            return .image(UIImage(systemName: "doc.on.doc.fill"))
        }
    }
  }
}


I said it in the staging ground and I say it again, you can’t use @ObservedObject outside of a view.

@JoakimDanielson I'm very new to developing and I was just following along with a video where it worked as it is above. Could you show me a way to correct this code as it is or give me some pointers?

You are using @ObservedObject in your Coordinator class and you can't do that. And instead of following along some random YouTube video why not find some good tutorials that really teach you the basics of Swift and SwifUI. 100 Days of SwiftUI is very popular and Paul Hudson is a great teacher.
